# Update config file for script via svn checkout

Tags: perl, svn

I need to write a script that is able to logon to an svn repository and checkout a config file for a script I am running on a lot of servers.

Perl is the only scripting language that I can use but I'm a complete novice in perl.

Could someone point me in the right direction and maybe give me some links with examples and/or documentation.

UPDATE:I can't install svn on the remote servers. Is it impossible to do without installing svn?

Gísli

Comment: Google the svn documentation, find how you do the checkout (or even look at `svn help` in the shell and then write a shell script to do it. You don't need Perl for that. It's just... one line, probably.

Comment: @simbabque I can't install svn on the remote servers. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: How about making the repository available trough http/browser with a login? It's not the most secure way to do it, but it would work. Here's a start: http://csoft.net/docs/svndav.html.en

Comment: Another thought... you could push the file from somewhere that has svn to all your servers through scp or sftp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LWP::Simple and fetch it over HTTP:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP::Simple;

my $config = get("http://username:password@svn.yourserver.com/configfile/");
```

or just use wget to fetch it before launching your script.